# Adding feature with duplicate ID to Vector source

Tags: openlayers-3

Right now, if I add two features with the same id to a Vector source, it seems like the second one is discarded. Is there anyway to force OpenLayers to replace features with the existing ids?

Answer (score -1):

```
var features=layer.getSource().getFeatures();
for(var i=0;i<features.length;i++){
      if(features[i].get('id')==id){
         layer.getSource().removeFeature(features[i]);
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

or from @sox:

```
layer.getSource().removeFeature(layer.getSource().getFeatureById(id));
```

Comment: you can also use [layer.getSource().getFeatureById(id)](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#getFeatureById) instead of looping through all the layer features